# How to store value of pointer in a recursive function?

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

Let say now I would like to write a function that search a certain node in a linked list recursively. When I successfully reached the targeted node, this function will return the ID and another information of it by reference, where its ID will be stored by struct:

```
struct P{
     int ID;
     int some_info;
     P* next_node;
}
```

The function will be something like

```
void search(int targeted_ID, P*& current_node){
     P* c = current_node;
     if(c->ID == targeted_ID){
           current_node = c;
     }
     if(c->next_node == nullptr){
           return;
     }
     else{
          search(ID, current_node->next_node);
     }
}
```

And the output statement will be something like

```
cout << "The targeted node have ID= " << current_node->ID << "with" << current_node->some_info << endl;
```

However, this function will recursively called by itself until all node has been reached and checked, and the value of pointer `current_node` will constantly changed throughout the process.

The main question is how can I remain the value of it unchanged when doing recursion.

p.s. There are constraints that:

1. Cannot add any global variable
2. Cannot use any static variable
3. Cannot add any parameters in the void function
4. Cannot use array
5. Cannot changed the `struct`'s content
6. The output statement cannot be changed
7. Cannot use `goto`

Comment: "_Cannot add any parameters in the void function_"? Why, Why not just return a pointer to the found node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive:

```
void search(int targeted_ID, P*& current_node) {
    if(current_node && current_node->ID != targeted_ID) {
         current_node = current_node->next_node;
         search(targeted_ID, current_node);
    }
}
```

But I suggest a non-recursive version to not get stack overflow when searching a long linked list:

```
void search(int targeted_ID, P*& current_node) {
    while(current_node && current_node->ID != targeted_ID)
        current_node = current_node->next_node;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zbdrEYT4T)

Answer (score 0):

I just coded a bit, as @Ted Lyngmo pointed out, you have to return a value, so you can't use a void-function.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct P {
    int ID;
    int some_info;
    P* next_node;
};


P* newNode(int ID, int some_info) {
    P* temp = new (std::nothrow) P;

    if (temp == nullptr){
        return nullptr;
    }
    else {
        temp->ID = ID;
        temp->some_info = some_info;
        temp->next_node = nullptr;
        return temp;
    }
}


P* search(int targeted_ID, P* current_node) {
    // check if current node is valid
    if (current_node == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    // check for ID of current node
    else if (current_node->ID == targeted_ID) {
        return current_node;
    }
    // this node isn't the desired one --> go to nex node
    else {
        return search(targeted_ID, current_node->next_node);
    }
}



void freeMem(P* list) {
    P* tmp = nullptr;

    while (list != nullptr) {
        tmp = list->next_node;
        delete list;
        list = tmp;
    }
}


int main()
{
    P* list = nullptr;
    P* tmp = nullptr;
    P* lastNode = nullptr;

    // populate list
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        tmp = newNode(i, i * 10);
    
        if (tmp == nullptr) {
            // error occured
            // free memory
            freeMem(list);
            list = nullptr;
            return -1;
        }

        if (list == nullptr) {
            // first node
            list = tmp;
            lastNode = list;
        }
        else {
            lastNode->next_node = tmp;
            lastNode = tmp;
        }
    }

    tmp = nullptr;
    lastNode = nullptr;

    int ID_to_find = 1;
    P* node = search(ID_to_find, list);

    if (node == nullptr) {
        // node not found ...
        std::cout << "node not found" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        // node found
        std::cout << "node found at: " << node << std::endl;
    }


    freeMem(list);
    list = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

This code works, but it is not really C++, it is more like C. If you want to write C++-Code use STL-Containers and don't write your own list, because it will be much more readable and the chance to have a bug is much smaller. Also consider to use exceptions instead of `(std::nothrow)`.